# How to broadcastTransaction in Tron network PHP

Tags: tron

I use iexbase and nile testnet to test the TRX transfer function of the tron ​​network. My code
public function tron_api(){
$fullNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://nile.trongrid.io');
$solidityNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://nile.trongrid.io');
$eventServer = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://nile.trongrid.io');
try {
$tron = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($fullNode, $solidityNode, $eventServer);
} catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
exit($e->getMessage());
}
$address = '...';
$tron->setAddress($address);

```
    $privateKey="...";
    $tron->setPrivateKey($privateKey);

    $output = [
        'sendResult' => $tron->send('...', 1),
    ];
    
    return response()->json($output);
}
```

but when I run code it respone "code": "SIGERROR", and I dont can broadcast it to tron nile tesnet network.

I want broadcast transfer to tron network